# Как правильно сделать языковую локализацию в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

В корне создана папка actions, в ней - индексный файл, где сверстана страница акций.

Здесь нужно вместо кириллицы вывести

```
<?=GetMessage("ACTIONS_ALL_ACTIONS");?>
```

А вот где разместить данный перевод?

Comment: Уже можно юзать d7 Loc::loadMessages(__FILE__); 
echo Loc::getMessage("ACTIONS_ALL_ACTIONS");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
__IncludeLang($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."ваш_путь"."/lang/".LANGUAGE_ID."/название_файла.php");
```